# Why is my python3 function running without being called?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, while-loop

Using python3.8 on macOS

I have a function with a while loop inside, and i also import two other .py files from the same directory which contain functions i need.

```
import Scraper
import Creator

def main(index=1):
    operation = True
    while operation == True:
        try:
            Scraper.scraper()
            Creator.Auto(index)

        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            operation = False

    return
```

Without calling `main()`, if i run my program it will still run the main() function. This also happens when i call `main()`, the program will then run using the while loop, but only after running through the function once before the while loop begins. (ie: the function will run one more time than expected)

I havent encountered a problem like this before. Any tips on fixing this?

Comment: Do you have code inside the other two file which is not inside a function?

Comment: Nothing standard is going to execute `main` automatically. If you don't need the `import` statements to reproduce the problem, get rid of them and explain *exactly* how you are executing the script. If you *do* need one or both `import` statements, the contents of the modules being imported are relevant.

Comment: Can you show the code from Scraper and Creator (assuming it is something you made). If they call main in this py file, that could cause this

Comment: Is it possible you have a code like this in one of those two imports?: ```if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()```

Comment: The function `traceback.print_stack` prints the current stacktrace. If you call it in `main` you can see what called `main`.

Comment: @chepner, i believe you are onto the root of the problem. I am, in fact, just an idiot. Both import files call functions from their respective files. Whenever i import both modules to this main.py, any function calls from the modules will also be called.

Comment: To answer your question, we'll have to see the contents of `Scraper.py` and `Creator.py`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to check other .py files. Once I had the same problem when my other .py files contained calls of the functions. When you import .py file and it contains call of the function, this function can be called automatically.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).